# How to remove character from inside a braces in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have data inside a square brackets. i need to remove character in side a braces.

ex:

```
(a-d){3-5},(A-F){5-8},(0-6){8-9},[#$%^&,+/]
```

as above example i need to remove comma(,) inside a square brackets.

i need output as below format.

```
(a-d){3-5},(A-F){5-8},(0-6){8-9},[#$%^&+/]
```

how to solve this using jquery or javascript.. ?

Regards
Nanda Kishore.CH

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.replace` method.

```js
var s = '(a-d){3-5},(A-F){5-8},(0-6){8-9},[#$%^&,+/]';
alert(s.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]/g, function(x){return x.replace(/,/g, '')}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to use  string.replace, using reg exp like this

```
var str = '(a-d){3-5},(A-F){5-8},(0-6){8-9},[#$%^&,+/]';
str= str.replace(/\,(?![\s\S]*\,)/,"");
```

Delete last ocurrence of "," in your string
expect it helps

Answer (score -1):

```js
var word = '(a-d){3-5},(A-F){5-8},(0-6){8-9},[#$%^&,+/]';
alert(word.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]/g, function(x){return x.replace(/,/g, '')}))
```

Comment: The only difference is the variable name.